# How to change a global variable with an if/else statement

Tags: javascript

I have this code where i want to change `var n` if  the `var thisRoll` is not `'green'`, but i only get `undefined` in the output from `console.log(n)`

```
var thisRoll = 'red'
var n;
var base_bet = 1;

function betInput(thisRoll, n) {
    var x;
    if (thisRoll === 'green') {
        x = base_bet;
        n = 0;
    } else {
        n = n + 1;
    }
    return x;
}
var X = betInput(thisRoll);
console.log(X);
console.log(n);
```

Shouldn't it add `1` when the `thisRoll` aren't `'green'`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because your `n` is also a parameter in the function. So it hides the outer variable `n` in the `function` and when you access the `n`, it refers to the `parameter variable`. To work with the global `n`, you need to remove the parameter, or change it's name.

```
function betInput(thisRoll) {
    var x;
    if (thisRoll === 'green') {
        x = base_bet;
        n = 0;
    } else {
        n = n + 1;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function `betInput(thisRoll, n)` contains a parameter `n` which *shadows* the global variable `n`. Calling that function using `betInput(thisRoll)` merely sets the local `n` to a default value.

(The fact that Javascript is lax on this - and many other things - does make it difficult to write stable code in the language).

Simply remove `n` from the function parameter list and all will be well.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parameter in your function. There's `n` there, which makes it scoped to the function.

```
function betInput(thisRoll, n) {
//------------------------^^^
```

Change your function to:

```
function betInput(thisRoll) {
```

So that, `n` will reference your global variable, otherwise `n` is undefined in your function scope