# How to change a global variable within an if else statement?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have declared a variable beforehand called:

```
var mathsLesson = 'https://www.link1.com';
```

The value of this variable will change

```
if (message.content === '!change') {           //this checks if the user messages !change
   mathsLesson = 'https://www.link2.com'
   message.channel.send(mathsLesson);          //This outputs www.link2.com
}
```

However when I output mathsLesson *outside* the if statement, it shows 'www.link1.com' instead of 'www.link2.com' which I wanted. How do I make it output 'www.link2.com'? Thanks in advance!

Comment: please create a reproducible example, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: is the if statement inside a function?

Comment: perhaps that statement does NOT resolve to true; try if(true){...}, or indeed, throwing the if statement out altogether, until it's working as expected.

Comment: the if statement looks wrong should that be not equal to change? !change seems like you are comparing content against a bool

Comment: I think you ment to compare `message.content` to '!change'.

Comment: what are the values of `message.content` and `change`? Should the condition be  `message.content !== change`?

Comment: `message.content` is a string. I'm assuming they ment to compate to `'!change'` not an inverted boolean

Comment: sorry for the confusion, message.content is used in discord.js and is when a user messages. so i this instance, if the user enters '!change' that happens. Also to answer a few questions, the statement is not in a function Ozgur Sar  . The statement is true, it is tested with a console log @HellishHeat

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change a global variable with an if/else statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867026/how-to-change-a-global-variable-with-an-if-else-statement)

Comment: try use regex to get only link don't get https://

Comment: This one is not reproducible. `mathsLesson` will only be updated if the statement is `true`. You should probably post more code; e.g. where you log the variable outside of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt be using a VAR or  CONST if the value of the variable tends the change. Dont use VAR because its pretty old and has many shortcomings change the var to let if you wanat the variable globally you can always export a function to return its value andmany other options

```
let mathsLesson = 'https://www.link1.com';
```

```
if (message.content === '!change') {           //this checks if the user messages !change
   let mathsLesson = 'https://www.link2.com'
   message.channel.send(mathsLesson);          //This outputs www.link2.com
}
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, using a `let` statement changes the value of the variable

Comment: Using `var` is perfectly fine. It's just as old as numbers or arrays in JS, and all of them have shortcomings we still don't ditch them. Your post doesn't answer OP's question though. `let` is blocked-scoped. If you create a variable with the same name using the `let` keyword inside the if statement, logging `mathsLesson` outside that block will never be link2, and that's what OP wanted.

Comment: Yes, i wanted to make it so link2 can be used outside that if else statement

Comment: you can give mathlesson an empty value outside the statment and just do mathlesson = link2

Answer (score 0):

Others have suggested that you should change `var` to `let`, but it won't make any difference. I'm not sure where you're checking the value, but as you can see below, it works as expected, if the statement is `true`:

```js
var mathsLesson = 'https://www.link1.com';
var message = {
  content: '!change'
};

console.log('outside if, before updating:', mathsLesson);

if (message.content === '!change') {
  mathsLesson = 'https://www.link2.com';
  console.log('inside if:', mathsLesson);
}

console.log('outside if, after updated:', mathsLesson);
```

And won't work if the statement is `false`:

```js
var mathsLesson = 'https://www.link1.com';
var message = {
  content: 'no command for you today'
};

console.log('outside if, before updating:', mathsLesson);

if (message.content === '!change') {
  mathsLesson = 'https://www.link2.com';
  console.log('inside if:', mathsLesson);
}

console.log('outside if, after updated:', mathsLesson);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
let mathsLesson = 'https://www.link1.com';
//The value of this variable will change

if (message.content === '!change') {           //this checks if the user messages 
   mathsLesson = 'https://www.link2.com'
   message.channel.send(mathsLesson);          //This outputs www.link2.com
}
```

Reason
"var" can not be renew

Comment: i wanted to make it so link2 can be used outside that if else statement

Comment: `var` can be updated and even re-declared. The difference between `let` and `var` is their scoping and that `var` is hoisted.

Comment: if you want the link2 to be used outside of if else statement,
you had to execute !change first.


Heres what i mean:

if you try to console.log(mathLesson) before executing the !change it will log the link1

but if you execute the !change
then you try console.log(mathLesson) it will log the link2